# Jquery keypress cascading

Tags: jquery, events, keypress

I have a few textboxes that need to accept only numbers less than 5. 
As the user enters a digit, some other events need to take place. The Keypress event works pretty well, except that when the user enters in textbox 1, the event is fired once (which is correct), and when he subsquently enters in textbox 2, the event is fired twice (is this correct?) - once for textbox 1, and another time for textbox 2. And if he backspaces, and enters a third number, the event is fired thrice.

I am new to jquery, so please pardon me if I am missing something simple. I would have thought it fires once for each keypress, but it seems like it is holding onto previous keypresses.

```
function validateInputKeyPress(e){

var element = document.getElementById(e.name);  

$("body").keypress(function(e) {
    var keycode= e.keyCode;
    alert(e.name); // this tells me which textbox
    if (keycode!=8){ //allow backspace
        if (keycode<49||keycode>53) { //if not a number less than 6
            return false; //disable key press
        }
    }
    handleQtyChange(e.name, keycode);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You've bind the event on `body`. You should bind the event on inputs.
You can use `stopPropagation` to stop event bubbling.

```
$("body").on('keypress', ':text', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```

This will bind the events only on textboxes, instead of `body`.

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: for me scenario looks different. He is saying event fired count depends on number of characters in textbox and not on number of ancestors, please correct me if I am wrong.